# Multiple problems trying to update with unmet dependencies and packages no longer required

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, mongodb

```
  ashin@ashin-Vostro-15-3568:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-database : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not installed
                        Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
ashin@ashin-Vostro-15-3568:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp javascript-common libboost-program-options1.71.0 libc-ares2
  libgoogle-perftools4 libjs-inherits libjs-is-typedarray libjs-psl
  libjs-typedarray-to-buffer libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal
  libpython2.7-stdlib libssl-dev libtcmalloc-minimal4 libuv1-dev
  libyaml-cpp0.6 mongodb-server-core node-abbrev node-ajv node-ansi
  node-ansi-align node-ansi-regex node-ansi-styles node-ansistyles node-aproba
  node-archy node-are-we-there-yet node-asap node-asn1 node-assert-plus
  node-asynckit node-aws-sign2 node-aws4 node-balanced-match node-bcrypt-pbkdf
  node-bl node-bluebird node-boxen node-brace-expansion node-builtin-modules
  node-builtins node-cacache node-call-limit node-camelcase node-caseless
  node-chalk node-chownr node-ci-info node-cli-boxes node-cliui node-clone
  node-co node-color-convert node-color-name node-colors node-columnify
  node-combined-stream node-concat-map node-concat-stream node-config-chain
  node-configstore node-console-control-strings node-copy-concurrently
  node-core-util-is node-cross-spawn node-crypto-random-string node-cyclist
  node-dashdash node-debug node-decamelize node-decompress-response
  node-deep-extend node-defaults node-define-properties node-delayed-stream
  node-delegates node-detect-indent node-detect-newline node-dot-prop
  node-duplexer3 node-duplexify node-ecc-jsbn node-editor node-encoding
  node-end-of-stream node-err-code node-errno node-es6-promise
  node-escape-string-regexp node-execa node-extend node-extsprintf
  node-fast-deep-equal node-find-up node-flush-write-stream node-forever-agent
  node-form-data node-from2 node-fs-vacuum node-fs-write-stream-atomic
  node-fs.realpath node-function-bind node-gauge node-genfun
  node-get-caller-file node-get-stream node-getpass node-glob node-got
  node-graceful-fs node-har-schema node-har-validator node-has-flag
  node-has-symbol-support-x node-has-to-string-tag-x node-has-unicode
  node-hosted-git-info node-http-signature node-iconv-lite node-iferr
  node-import-lazy node-imurmurhash node-inflight node-inherits node-ini
  node-invert-kv node-ip node-ip-regex node-is-npm node-is-obj node-is-object
  node-is-path-inside node-is-plain-obj node-is-retry-allowed node-is-stream
  node-is-typedarray node-isarray node-isexe node-isstream node-isurl
  node-jsbn node-json-parse-better-errors node-json-schema
  node-json-schema-traverse node-json-stable-stringify
  node-json-stringify-safe node-jsonify node-jsonparse node-jsonstream
  node-jsprim node-latest-version node-lazy-property node-lcid node-libnpx
  node-locate-path node-lockfile node-lodash node-lodash-packages
  node-lowercase-keys node-lru-cache node-make-dir node-mem node-mime
  node-mime-types node-mimic-fn node-mimic-response node-minimatch
  node-minimist node-mississippi node-mkdirp node-move-concurrently node-ms
  node-mute-stream node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npm-bundled
  node-npm-package-arg node-npm-run-path node-npmlog node-number-is-nan
  node-oauth-sign node-object-assign node-once node-opener node-os-locale
  node-os-tmpdir node-osenv node-p-cancelable node-p-finally node-p-is-promise
  node-p-limit node-p-locate node-p-timeout node-package-json
  node-parallel-transform node-path-exists node-path-is-absolute
  node-path-is-inside node-performance-now node-pify node-prepend-http
  node-process-nextick-args node-promise-inflight node-promise-retry
  node-promzard node-proto-list node-prr node-pseudomap node-psl node-pump
  node-pumpify node-punycode node-qs node-qw node-rc node-read
  node-read-package-json node-readable-stream node-registry-auth-token
  node-registry-url node-request node-require-directory
  node-require-main-filename node-resolve node-resolve-from node-retry
  node-rimraf node-run-queue node-safe-buffer node-semver node-semver-diff
  node-set-blocking node-sha node-shebang-command node-shebang-regex
  node-signal-exit node-slash node-slide node-sorted-object node-spdx-correct
  node-spdx-exceptions node-spdx-expression-parse node-spdx-license-ids
  node-sshpk node-ssri node-stream-each node-stream-iterate node-stream-shift
  node-strict-uri-encode node-string-decoder node-string-width node-strip-ansi
  node-strip-eof node-strip-json-comments node-supports-color node-tar
  node-term-size node-text-table node-through node-through2 node-timed-out
  node-tough-cookie node-tunnel-agent node-tweetnacl node-typedarray
  node-typedarray-to-buffer node-uid-number node-unique-filename
  node-unique-string node-unpipe node-uri-js node-url-parse-lax
  node-url-to-options node-util-deprecate node-uuid
  node-validate-npm-package-license node-validate-npm-package-name node-verror
  node-wcwidth.js node-which node-which-module node-wide-align
  node-widest-line node-wrap-ansi node-wrappy node-write-file-atomic
  node-xdg-basedir node-xtend node-y18n node-yallist node-yargs
  node-yargs-parser nodejs-doc python-pkg-resources python2 python2-minimal
  python2.7 python2.7-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/44.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 185 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 201407 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_5.0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (5.0.6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_5.0.6_
amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-
core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_5.0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (5.0.6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_5.0.6_
amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-
core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_5.0.6_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_5.0.6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ashin@ashin-Vostro-15-3568:~$
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context? What have you been up to? What software have you installed, changed, or removed since the last time you were able to update successfully? You have about a hundred dependent packages related to node and python that are no longer needed. Do you have an idea how this happened? Did you try to install a different version of python than the one in your distro? What were you doing with node?

Comment: Problem #1: You are not reading your apt output, which is suggesting normal maintenance that you apparently are not doing.

Comment: recently i installed mongodb servaral times, so installed many times and many.Then from this site i got the solution for this problem , the ans was `unmask` the mongodb. then the problem solved. But after some time i enter `sudo apt upgrade` i got lot of warning like this   `   W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:60 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1`        then i got above error. after refer some to fix this problem i also install some `python ##'  . then finally am here

Comment: Problem #2: Looks like you tried to install mongodb, failed, neglected to clean up (see Problem #1), and then tried to install mongodb a different way. Your output seems quite clear that the leftovers from previous install of mongodb packages are in conflict with newer packages that you want to install.

Comment: The solution seems obvious: Basic cleanup and maintenance. The Ubuntu equivalent of brushing your teeth. Everything you need is already in the apt output you provided.

Comment: how to fix this?

Comment: Let's start with the easy one. Look for the instruction around line 86: "*Use ______ to remove them*". Use that command to remove 70 lines of orphaned packages.

Comment: `ashin@ashin-Vostro-15-3568:~$ sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for ashin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-database : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not installed
                        Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`
           is that proper output?